# Unused Variable Warning in ReasonML

Tags: reason

When I use Invalid_argument() variant exception in a switch case, it expects a string argument.

```
let subStr = try(String.sub(input^, index, 1)) {
  | Invalid_argument(err) => ""
};
```

but if I don't use the `err` variable, it shows an unused variable warning.

Answer (score 1):

Unused variables are prefixed by a _ in Reason.

Instead of

```
Invalid_argument(err)
```

you have to use

```
Invalid_argument(_err)
```